Angular dev server got broken with the v18 upgrade
With the Angular 17.3 -> 18.0 upgrade, the local dev server (ng serve) got broken. We use it to connect the local dev instance to our backends in the cloud, for development. There were no config changes, only dependencies and unrelated code level migrations.
After the upgrade, some of the API requests were successful, but some returned 404, so working with the local dev server was not really possible any more. More specifically, some requests always worked, and some others always failed with 404, and it was seemingly random which ones. E.g. /api/v1/me and /api/v1/project?usedIn=false always worked, but some others like /api/v1/permissions/<username> always failed.

In our proxy-conf.json, we had to change the path wildcards from:
{
  "/rest/v1/*": {
    "target": "https://company-fqdn.com:9080/app/api",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {"^/rest" : ""}
  }
}

to "/rest/v1/**", note the double asterisks. The requests that were successful only had a single path section after /rest/v1/ and the ones that did not were the ones that had multiple path sections.
Explanation and the steps I took to discover this:

ng serve --verbose outputs verbose info about what the dev proxy does
It said that the requests that were successful are being successfully proxied, but for the ones that returned 404 in the browser, the log said Not rewriting <method> <url> because the client prefers JSON
Some research showed that this is the error message by some middleware library for the case when the usual SPA setup (always serve the index.html so that the client routing can kick in) receives a request with the Accept header specifying JSON, so the library can't respond with the index.html
Started to look into what might be the library that does the parsing of the proxy config. Starting from https://angular.dev/tools/cli/serve#proxying-to-a-backend-server ended up looking at https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy and some other stuff
Somehow http-proxy-middleware also came up. Checked the docs of that, and multiple of the examples showed the ** syntax for a complete wildcard, instead of a single * which is rather just for a single part of the URL. Changing this solved the issue.
Looked into the package-lock.json to check whether http-proxy-middleware was upgraded, as it is a transitive dependency, and indeed, it went from 2.0.6 to 3.0.0, which may or may not be the direct cause of the issue.


This worked for me - thanks!

Spent two days trying to fix this issue on my own before I found your post - thank you!
